# Ассоциация многие к одному extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

Привет .

> Связь нескольких моделей
> Ext JS 4 предоставляет возможность
> связать или ассоциировать несколько
> моделей друг с другом. Например, одна
> книга может иметь двух авторов,
> реализуя связь один-ко-многим
> (one-to-many).
>
> Фреймворк Ext JS 4 три подобных
> отношения или типа связей:
>
> Один ко многим (One-to-many) (тип
> Ext.data.HasManyAssociation)
>
> Многие к одному (Many-to-one) (тип
> Ext.data.BelongsToAssociation)
>
> Один к одному (Has-one) (тип
> Ext.data.association.HasOne)
> Меня сейчас интересует Ассоциация многие к одному
> Есть пример

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.define('Company', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
        name: 'Title',
        type: 'string'
        },{
        name: 'Date',
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'd-m-Y'
        }, {
        name: 'Value',
        type: 'int'
        }]
    });

    Ext.define('Manager', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
        name: 'FirstName',
        type: 'string'
        }, {
        name: 'LastName',
        type: 'string'
        }],
        belongsTo: 'Company'
    });
    var manager = Ext.create('Manager', {
        FirstName: 'Bill',
        LastName: 'Gates'
    });
     var company = Ext.create('Company', {
        Title: 'Microsoft',
        Date: '01-01-1974',
        Value: 30000
    });
    manager.setCompany(company);
    manager.getCompany(function(company, operation){
        alert(company.get('Title'));
    });
});
```

Я здесь не увидел многие к одному ....Как добавить еще один объект к   manager  ?

Answer (score 1):

> belongsTo: 'Company'

добавляет ссылку на *Company* в модель *Manager*. У каждого *Manager* есть только одна ссылка *Company*. В данном примере получилась связь многие(Manager) к одному(Company). Чтобы использовать несколько компаний в *Manager*, нужно заменить `belongsTo: 'Company'` на `hasMany: 'Company'`. После этого у объекта *manager* появится метод **companies()**, который возвращает Store с моделью Company. И работать с ним просто:

```
manager.companies().add(company);
manager.companies().add(company2);
```

и т.д.